# Webpack 4 + react @media

Tags: reactjs, media

Очень нужна помощь 
Webpack 4 + React

Единственная но очень большая проблема, что `@media` - запросы не работают так как нужно. В данном случае они должны были сработать на точке 576 и выше, а сработали 518 и выше

````
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;

}


  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .sdfsdfsdf{
        background: green;
      }
  }``

При этом начинает работать на точке 518
``` rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: '/node_modules/'
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        }, {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: `${PATHS.src}/js/postcss.config.js` } }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        }
      ]
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        }, {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: `${PATHS.src}/js/postcss.config.js` } }
        }
      ]
    }]
  },```
````

Comment: Единственная но очень большая проблема, что @media - запросы не работают так как нужно. В данном случае они должны были сработать на точке 576 и выше, а сработали 518 и выше

Comment: попробуйте использовать @media (max-width: ?px) вместо min-width

Comment: Возможно ошибаюсь, но попробуйте в самом верху стилей подключить какой-то reset стилей. Мой вариант на sass https://jsfiddle.net/DemoS/b8m7jhf1/